# How to sympify initial conditions for ODE in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I am passing initial conditions as string, to be used to solving an ODE in sympy.

It is a first order ode, so for example, lets take initial conditions as `y(0):3` for example.  From [help](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html)

> ics is the set of initial/boundary conditions for the differential
>   equation. It should be given in the form of {f(x0): x1,
>   f(x).diff(x).subs(x, x2): x3}

I need to pass this to `sympy.dsolve`. But `sympify(ic)`  gives an error for some reason.

What other tricks to use to make this work? Here is MWE. First one shows it works without initial conditions being string (normal mode of operation)

```
from sympy import *
x   = Symbol('x')
y   = Function('y')
ode = Eq(Derivative(y(x),x),1+2*x)
sol = dsolve(ode,y(x),ics={y(0):3})
```

gives sol `Eq(y(x), x**2 + x + 3)`

Now the case when ics is string

```
from sympy import *
ic  = "y(0):3"
x   = Symbol('x')
y   = Function('y')
ode = Eq(Derivative(y(x),x),1+2*x)
sol = dsolve(ode,y(x),ics={ sympify(ic) })
```

gives

> SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse 'y(0):3'' failed,
>   because of exception being raised: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   (, line 1)

So looking at [sympify webpage](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.sympify)

```
  sympify(a, locals=None, convert_xor=True, strict=False, rational=False, evaluate=None)
```

And tried changing different options as shown above, still the syntax error shows up.

I also tried

```
sol = dsolve(ode,y(x),ics= { eval(ic) } )
```

But this gives syntax error as well

Is there a trick to use to convert this initial conditions string to something sympy is happy with?

Python 4.7 with sympy 1.5

---

As **temporary work around**, currently I do this

```
from sympy import *
ic  = "y(0):3"
ic  = ic.split(":")
x   = Symbol('x')
y   = Function('y')
ode = Eq(Derivative(y(x),x),1+2*x)
sol = dsolve(ode,y(x),ics= {S(ic[0]):S(ic[1])} )
```

Which works. So the problem is with `:` initially, `sympify` (or `S`) do not handle `:` it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sympify('{y(0):3}')`.

I don't know what your actual goal is but I don't recommend parsing strings like this in general. The format for ICs is actually slightly awkward so that for a second order ODE it looks like:

```py
ics = '{y(0):3, y(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0):1}'
```

If you're parsing a string then you can come up with a better syntax than that like

```py
ics = "y(0)=3, y'(0)=1"
```

Also you should use `parse_expr` rather than converting strings with `sympify` or `S`:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr

Comment: But the string that is passed in is `"y(0):3"` and not `"{y(0):3}"` as you show, and hence it does not work when using `S( ic )` when `ic="y(0):3"`. This was one of the things I tried before as mentioned. Ofcourse, I can change the input to become `"{y(0):3}"` instead to make it work. I was just wondering how to make it work with `"y(0):3"`. I will look at `parse_expr` to see if works.

Comment: The string `"y(0):3"` is not a valid expression in any language I know so you'll need to make your own parsing code or just wrap the string in brackets.